# How to set Featured Image on WordPress post page by Selenium from java?

Tags: java, wordpress, selenium, dialog

**My purpose is post with a Featured Image.**

This program can post Featured Image.
But dialog doesn't close!
So I can't publish.

```
public void uploadThumbnail(String imgPath) {
    //parent current window
    String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

    System.out.println(imgPath);
    try {
    driver.findElement(By.id("set-post-thumbnail")).click();
    sleep(2000);
    click(By.linkText("Upload Files"));
    //Select Files
    sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("__wp-uploader-id-1")).click();
    //upload
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[7]/input")).sendKeys(imgPath);
    sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='__wp-uploader-id-0']/div[5]/div/div[2]/button")).click();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        uploadThumbnail(imgPath);
    }
    sleep(1000);
}
```

How to close the dialog or how to ignore the dialog and publish?

Comment: Hi Teramoto - can you give some details of what the screen elements are; for example a small screenshot of the dialog, and a paste of the relevant bits of html?  Also, if you could show how you've _tried_ so far to close the dialog, and describe how that hasn't worked so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I stacked on the page.Finally I find plugin which is **"[Nelio External Featured Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/external-featured-image/)"**.

it is can set picture by URL.So I don't need upload window and dialog.

Now I can set a picture on Featured Image on WordPress by Selenium from java!!!

Thank you Nelio External Featured Image developers!!